# ImportError: No module named tis_class

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, raspberry-pi

I've a Python3 script, normally works great.

But I've this module error message in line 5 :

```
    pi@raspberrypi ~ $ python3 ScriptCompteur.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ScriptCompteur.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tis_class as TIS
ImportError: No module named tis_class
```

Can you help me ?

Below a part of the script :

```
import requests
import json
import time
import serial
import tis_class as TIS
#variables
portserie='/dev/ttyUSB0'
baudrate=9600
timeout_serial=2
temps_attente=10 #30 secondes
periode=15 #mesure de l'information pendant cette periode
sense_key="4bgd5Q8_6Oc4V8m2eDK_0g"
sense_url="http://api.sen.se/events/"
sense_head={'Content-type': 'application/json', 'sense_key':sense_key}
sense_feed=26341
stick=TIS.TeleInfo(portserie,baudrate,timeout_serial)
#initialisation
minute_debut=time.strftime('%M')

...
...
```

Comment: what is this TIS module and where does it come from?

Comment: It's interesting that you say "normally works great". What exactly works great normally? Do you not get this error message every time you run the script?

Comment: It's works with another Raspberry Pi.
I have installed another Raspberry and with it, this script doesn't works...

Comment: @gloops100 Then I suspect you simply didn't install the `tis_class` module.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro I try to install the module with :  sudo apt-get install python3-dev tis_class
but unable to locate the package

Comment: @gloops100 run `python -c "import tis_class; print tis_class.__file__"` on your machine where script runs successfully to locate tis_class. From TeleInfo args it seems that this is a custom wrapper over [Serial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html)

Comment: @alko It returns this :
pi@raspberrypi / $ python -c "import tis_class; print tis_class.__file__"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tis_class

Comment: @gloops100 on machine where **script runs successfully** (I guess it exists from your `normally works great`)

Comment: @alko Oh yes ! Ok I will try this, but I don't have the machine where the script runs successfully with mine today...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't find the module `tis_class`. As this doesn't seem to be a commonly available library it's probably a custom module in your system. It can't be found either because it's not on the path where Python looks for modules, or because it itself imports something that has a syntax error, which in some cases gives errors like this.

Comment: Where I can find the path of the module ?
Thanks for your quick answer :)

Comment: @gloops100 You can find the path of the module by using the search functionality of your operating system, assuming it's installed, which it probably isn't.

Comment: In : /usr/local/lib/ , I've 3 folders : python2.6  python2.7  python3.2. 
In python3.2 folder I've : dist-packages
But it's all.

Comment: @gloops100: Whatever you did to install it on the machine where it is installed, do the same thing on the machine where it is not installed. We can not magically know how to install a random module that we don't know what it is and which the internet [knows nothing about](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=tis_class&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=%22tis_class%22+python). Where did you get `tis_class` from in the first place?

Comment: I've finally found the tis_class.py on the other machine ! It works now !!!
Thank you all for your support ! :)